# AutoHotkey simple script doesn't work when run from a shared folder connected by VPN

Tags: exe, autohotkey, compiled

I have a simple script that runs from a shared folder on a server.
When I run it from the same network where the server is, everything runs smooth, but when I'm not on the same network and I establish a VPN connection before running it, it returns an error message.

The script:

```
url = %1%
reservation = %2%
status = %3%
uid = %4%
ex_id = %5%

variables = {"id":"%reservation%", "status":"%status%", "uid":"%uid%", 
"ex_id":"%ex_id%"}

WebRequest := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
WebRequest.Open("PUT", url, false)
WebRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
WebRequest.Send(variables)
Return
```

The error is 0x80072726 - An invalid argument was supplied.
Specifically: Send

```
WebRequest.Send(variables)
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5Amz.jpg)
Any help would be greatly appreciated because I'm stuck here.

Comment: Welcome.  Didja try it like `WebRequest.Send(%variables%)` ?  I guess since it works as interpreted, that's _not_ the issue . . .  Try quoting each independant command line variable, or put in a msg box that displays what each variable is first to debug.

Comment: Thanks PGilm but I discovered new clues and updated the thread... any more ideas?

Comment: can you recreate the request in something like Postman while you're on and off the VPN? Definitely sounds like it's a network related error and nothing with the code

Comment: Are you running a compiled script?  Try at the top of your code the following directives: `#NoEnv` and `SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%` and re-compile.  You could also try making two different shortcuts, one using the express Server paths to executable and working directory, and the other using the VPN network paths (probably different drive letters).